# How can I handle 'stacked' flyouts in my 8.1 universal app?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, flyout

```
Flyout flyout = new Flyout();

Button button = new Button();
button.Content = "open";
button.Flyout = flyout;

StackPanel stack = new StackPanel();

ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();

int[] arr = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
comboBox.ItemsSource = arr;

stack.Children.Add(comboBox);

Button closeButton = new Button();
closeButton.Content = "close";
closeButton.Click += delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
                            //saving stuff
    flyout.Hide();
};
stack.Children.Add(closeButton);

flyout.Content = stack;
```

When I open the combobox, it accesses its own flyout to let the user select a number. Doing this closes the flyout I have made. How do I prevent my flyout from closing until the user pressed the closeButton?

Comment: I don't think you can, the default behavior for the ComboBox Flyout is the one you're experiencing